# How many combinations are possible with 10 numbers and 28 letters

Tags: combinations

I am trying to figure out the maximum possible combinations of 10 numbers and 28 letters, with the following form:

$N N N L L L L$

Where $N$ is number and $L$ is letter.

What I think the max maximum possible combinations is but not sure as follow:
$28^4$ $*$ $10^3$ $=$ $614,656,000,000,000$

Comment: Well, $28^4\times 10^3$ is correct but you have too many zeroes in the written out form.   Just doing it mentally, it must be less than $3^4\times 10^7$ which is much smaller than your number.

Comment: $28^4  \cdot 10^3 = 614,656,000$

Comment: Yeah, take off 6 zeros and you have the right answer

Answer (score 1):

It is just a miscalculation.

There are $10\times10\times10=10^3$ way to choose the three numbers and $28\times28\times28\times28=28^4$ ways to choose the four letters.

Hence, there are $28^4\times10^3=614,656,000$ possible combinations.